# Delete form input value outside of input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, redux

So I have this form that updates the search in real time via storeUserSearch, which is why a value isn't set on input. I'm trying to implement an icon that deletes what's in the input field on click, and also runs the action storeUserSearch('').

The second onClick has no problems by itself. I'm simply trying to get the first onClick to work, and then have them both running at the same time so my click executes both.

```
<form>
  <input
    className="searchBox fas fa-search"
    type="search"
    placeholder="Search"
    onChange={event => this.props.storeUserSearch(event.target.value) } />
    <i className="fas fa-times-circle" onClick={event => event.target.parentElement.input} onClick={event => this.props.storeUserSearch('')}> </i>
</form>
```

**Edit:** Figured out how to reset the value via

```
onClick={event => event.target.parentElement.firstChild.value=''}
```

Just need to figure out how to combine the onClicks now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why you're writing two onClick on same element? just pass a method on its click event and write all the logic there.
i.e:

```
<i className="fas fa-times-circle" onClick={this.handleIconClick}> </i>
// and in handleIconClick function write the logic.
handleIconClick = (e)=>{
  e.target.parentElement.firstChild.value='';
  this.props.storeUserSearch('');
}
```

Comment: Good point. Dunno why I didn't try this instead. Probably lack of sleep.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define two `onClick` props, one will overwrite the other. You can try something like

```
onClick={(event) => {event.target.parentElement.firstChild.value=''; this.props.storeUserSearch('')}}
```

note the semi-colon between the two individual statements

Comment: This code gives me a failed to compile error. Inside the console is a parsing error: unexpected token on the closing </i>. I tried writing it in manually then I tried copy pasting. Error both times.

Comment: @RobertC What about this `<i className="fas fa-times-circle" onClick={event => event.target.parentElement.input; this.props.storeUserSearch('');}> </i>`

Comment: @Abk That doesn't work  either. Gives me Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}" and cites the semicolon as the problem, in console.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have 1 `onClick` attribute per component, not multiple. I'm not sure exactly what `storeUserSearch` function is supposed to do since it's omitted from your code snippet, but based on what you've explained, I think you can achieve what you want to do similar to below:

```js
class SearchForm extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      inputValue: ''
    };
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
         <input 
            type="text"
            value={ this.state.inputValue }
            onChange={ 
              e => {
               this.setState({inputValue: e.target.value}) 
              } 
            }
          />
            
          <input 
            type="button" 
            value="Clear input" 
            onClick={
              () => { 
                this.setState({inputValue: ''}) 
              }
            }/>
          
          <span style={{ display: 'block' }}>Current textbox state: <span style={{ color: 'blue' }}>{this.state.inputValue}</span></span>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SearchForm></SearchForm>, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Basically we create a component that is made up of a 2 `input` elements (1 `text` and 1 `button`). The approach I took was to simply set the `value` attribute equal to our component's `state.inputValue`, which is updated each time a `change` event occurs on it.

We just hardcode the `state.inputValue` property to `''` when the clear button is pressed.